# Grep for a name-value pair inside a JSON object

Tags: json, bash, unix, grep

Have a shell script running on Unix that is going through a list of JSON objects like the following, collecting values like `&lt;init&gt;() @ JSONInputData.java:82`. There are also other objects with other values that I need to retrieve.

Is there a better option than grepping for `"STACKTRACE_LINE",\n\s*.*` and then splitting up that result?

inb4: "add X package to the OS". Need to run generically.

```
. . .
"probableStartLocationView" : {
  "lines" : [ {
    "fragments" : [ {
      "type" : "STACKTRACE_LINE",
      "value" : "&lt;init&gt;() @ JSONInputData.java:82"
    } ],
    "text" : "&lt;init&gt;() @ JSONInputData.java:82"
  } ],
  "nested" : false
},
. . . .
```

What if I was looking for `"description" : "Dangerous Data Received"` in a series of objects like the following knowing that I need to know that it is associated with event 12345 and not with another event listed in the same file?

```
. . .
"events" : [ {
  "id" : "12345",
  "important" : true,
  "type" : "Creation",
  "description" : "Dangerous Data Received",
  . . .
```

Comment: Take a look at a JSON parser such as `jq` or use a scripting language which understands JSON. If you want answers, it would be best to post a more complete example of valid JSON (not the whole thing, just enough to be representative).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better option than grepping for "STACKTRACE_LINE",\n\s*.* and then splitting up that result?

Yes. Use `jq` to filter and extract the interesting parts.

Example 1, given this JSON:

```
{
  "probableStartLocationView": {
    "lines": [
      {
        "fragments": [
          {
            "type": "STACKTRACE_LINE",
            "value": "&lt;init&gt;() @ JSONInputData.java:82"
          }
        ],
        "text": "&lt;init&gt;() @ JSONInputData.java:82"
      }
    ],
    "nested": false
  }
}
```

Extract `value` where `type` is "STACKTRACE_LINE":

```
jq -r '.probableStartLocationView.lines[] | .fragments[] | select(.type == "STACKTRACE_LINE") | .value' file.json
```

This is going to produce one line per `value`.

Example 2, given this JSON:

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "id": "12345",
      "important": true,
      "type": "Creation",
      "description": "Dangerous Data Received"
    }
  ]
}
```

Extract the `id` where `description` starts with "Dangerous":

```
jq -r '.events[] | select(.description | startswith("Dangerous")) | .id'
```

And so on.
See the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for more examples and capabilities.
Also there are many questions on Stack Overflow using `jq`,
that should help you find the right combination of filtering and extracting the relevant parts.